# <%=values%> are not updating inside an update panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, dygraphs

I have tried almost all the suggested solutions which are posted here and are related to my issue with no luck. I am creating some graphs (using [Dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/) library). The following javascript code is just a small part of the whole function; in fact I create 5 graphs in such way.

```
<script>

    designRawGraphs();

    function designRawGraphs()
    {

                var g1 = new Dygraph(
                document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
                [ <%=sDataForROI1Graph%> ],
            { 
                labels: <%=sLabelsForROI1Graph%>,
                connectSeparatedPoints: true,
                animatedZooms: true,
                highlightCircleSize: 3,
                highlightSeriesOpts: {
                    highlightCircleSize: 6
                },
                drawPoints: true,
                title: 'ROI 1 - Region of Interest',
                ylabel: 'Raw Fluorence Intensity',
                xlabel: 'Time (seconds)' 
            }
                        );

    }
</script>
```

In the code behind, I serialize (and serve as a `String`) both the *sDataForROI1Graph* and *sLabelsForROI1Graph* global variables which are filled in with the result of a database query in a specific format (the expected format for Dygraphs). This javascript code is located inside of an `asp:UpdatePanel`. When I fire a button (which is also inside of the same UpdatePanel) the query returns different results, so both the *sDataForROI1Graph* and *sLabelsForROI1Graph* are changed but the graphs are not redesigned (namely the values of the global variables are not passing from the code behind to client-side with the <%= => technique). I have also declared the `Trigger` option to the fired button as shown below...

```
   <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RemoveAllbtn" />
   </Triggers>
```

... and my code is just simple as shown in the following snippet (actually I re-run a stored procedure which updates the 2 global variables *sDataForROI1Graph* and *sLabelsForROI1Graph* with new values)

```
Protected Sub RemoveAllbtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles RemoveAllbtn.Click
    RemoveAll()
End Sub
```

If I remove the UpdatePanel, everything works like a charm, because a full post-back occurs. I have tried to inject javascript code and perform other tricky suggestions but I haven't found a workaround yet.

My question is why these 2 global variables can't be accessed from client-side when are nested to the UpdatePanel? Which is the best approach to bypass this issue? I have also read about hidden Textboxes / HiddenFields / Labels / Literals controls, but even these approaches didn't help me to solve my issue.

**EDIT**

Admittedly, the suggested answer below is what I needed and it works fine, **BUT** after a lot of hours spending on my issue and banging my head against the wall, I realized that my problem persists and the reason is too weird. In client side, outside of the `UpdatePanel` I have created an `<asp:HiddenField ID="hidfieldforROI1" runat="server"/>` , that I am trying to get its value like this

```
var dataforROI1 = document.getElementById('<%= hidfieldforROI1.ClientID %>').value;
```

In the back-end I am setting the `Value` to the hidfieldforROI1 Control. And I am getting the following weird error:

`error BC30451: 'dataforROI1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Replace it with a `Literal` Control? `[ <asp:Literal ID="sDataForROI1Graph" runat="server"></asp:Literal> ],`

Comment: @VDWWD could you please let me know how to get the Literal Text in client-side using javascript?

Comment: You can't. You set the value of the literal in code behind. `sDataForROI1Graph.Text = "yourJavaScriptStringValue";` It gives exactly the same result client side if you would use the `<%= yourJavaScriptStringValue %>`

Comment: What I want to do is to pass the text from the code behind to client side, not the opposite. Your suggestion, indeed, gives the same result with the `<%=stringvalue%>` approach. But my problem is that the `javascript` code that creates the graphs, gets 2 initial values for  `<%=sDataForROI1Graph%>` and for `<%=sLabelsForROI1Graph%>` which are not changed in client-side even if they are changing in the code behind.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Ignore my previous comments. You probably need to call `designRawGraphs()` again to rebuild the graph. Put his in code behind `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, "designRawGraphs", "designRawGraphs();", true)`

Comment: I have tried this approach but unfortunately with no luck. I put this piece of code in the first line of `Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load` and I also added an `alert(<%=sDataForROI1Graph%>);` in client side to observe the changes. Unfortunately the `sDataForROI1Graph` gives always the same value in front-end, but in back-end it changes. I am so confused with the Page's lifecycle when there are `UpdatePanel`s in general.

Comment: Are you sure you put everything inside the `UpdatePanel`? I will post a simple demo. There everything works as I think you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the aspx file

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <div id="testdiv"><%= sDataForROI1Graph %></div>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
        <br />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function testScript() {
                alert(document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML);
                var dataforROI1 = document.getElementById('<%= hidfieldforROI1.ClientID %>').value;
                alert(dataforROI1);
            }
        </script>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:TextBox ID="hidfieldforROI1" runat="server" Text="textBoxje"></asp:TextBox>
```

And then in code behind

```
Dim sDataForROI1Graph As String = DateTime.Now.ToString

Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    hidfieldforROI1.Text = "Page Load"
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    sDataForROI1Graph = DateTime.Now.ToString

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, "testScript", "testScript();", true)
End Sub
```

If I use this code, the `sDataForROI1Graph` is updated after a button click and displayed with the alert.

UPDATE

I altered my answer a bit to include a HiddenField (TextBox in my snippet to make visualisation easier). The HiddenField get a value in `Page_load' and in`Button1_Click`. The one in`Button1_Click`will ofcourse not show up since the`HiddenField`is outside the`UpdatePanel`. But the properties are still available so you can still use`hidfieldforROI1.ClientID`inside the`UpdatePanel`

Comment: I edited my post, because I realized that the problem still persists and the reason is little different than my first explanation.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a `HiddenField` outside the `UpdatePanel`. But your error message has nothing to do with the updatepanel. Either `dataforROI1` does not exist (missing an `s`? > `sDataForROI1Graph`) or it is declared somewhere without `public`? (`Public dataforROI1 As String = "myString"`)